# TYPO3: Using URL Alias in HMENU

Tags: menu, typo3, alias

I have a page tree structure in my TYPO3 project with a page called 'main' which has three subpages. In addition to it's unique pageID I gave the page 'main' a unique URL Alias 'mainalias'.

I can use the alias to add a link to the page 'main' e.g. in using

```
<f:link.page pageUid="mainalias">some text</f:link.page>
```

in a template.html or in TypoScript e.g. to add a link to an IMAGE with

```
stdWrap.typolink.parameter = mainalias
```

But when I use the alias to define the starting point of a HMENU the menu will contain no data (I simply get in empty menu but no error message in the logs):

```
special = directory
special.value = mainalias
```

The menu itself works and when in the code above I use the pageID of the page 'main' instead of it's alias 'mainalias' I get a menu with the three subpages as expected.

**Can you tell me how to use the URL Alias to define the starting point of a HMENU?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest and most possible answer is: It is not implemented in HMENU to use an alias. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But just to ensure that I understood you correct. Did you say: "It is not implemented in HMENU to use an alias"? So you mean I may can use aliases in URLs and to some degree elsewhere in code but I can't use it in HMENU? But why? Can you shortly explain what aliases are basically made for - I obviously seem not to have understood the concept of aliases at all :-(

Comment: The aliases were implemented long time ago and in my opinion it was for the possibility to use it in the URL (`index.php?id=myalias` instead of `index.php?id=42`). I didn't know that it was even possible to use it as typolink parameter. In these cases (typolink and HMENU) I would suggest to use the `UID` of the page, better use it via a TypoScript constant.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I feared it to be so. As beeing bound to use numeric IDs I tried to use at least aliases for better readibility and re-usability of code. And it seems a bit inconsequent of TYPO3 that aliases work in some cases and not in others. But as I haven't found any other information before, your answer seems quite likely. So I tend to make it the accepted answer, as sad as it may be. But before doing so I want to give some time to find out whether Heinz Schilling's answer would still turn out to be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Common way to use HMENU is

```
10 = HMENU
10.special = directory
10.special.value = 35, 56
```

A alias is not a valid value. But value is from data type **stdWrap**. This should work:

```
10 = HMENU
10.special = directory
10.special.stdWrap.typolink.parameter = mainalias
```

See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html#special-directory

Comment: Thanks you for this answer. It sounded great to me but when I changed "special.value = mainalias" to "special.stdWrap.typolink.parameter = mainalias" the menu was still empty. Did I understood you wrong? (Just to notice: I haven't shown the whole structure of my menu, but I assume this would be of no problem as the menu works fine with "special.value = <numeric_page_ID>")